# cassandra dsbulk mapping failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra, dsbulk

I am using dsbulk to load dataset into the datastax astra

error message:
[image]

my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE project(
 FL_DATE date, 
 OP_CARRIER text, 
 DEP_DELAY float, 
 ARR_DELAY float, 
 PRIMARY KEY ((FL_DATE), OP_CARRIER)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (OP_CARRIER ASC);
```

my mapping error

[image]
[image]

i try changing datatype still not working. Appreciate if anyone can help me

Comment: I tried to edit the csv file and even build my own csv file to import, it doesn't work. However, it works when i used the datastax dataset https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-upload-data.html. i am totally lost now. please help me

Comment: Are you sure, that there no null entries for FL_DATE or OP_CARRIER in your csv?

Comment: Please post the output of `mapping.bad` & `mapping-errors.log` files content here to analyze. Also, post the complete command that you ran along with configuration files, if any (of course, passwords masked). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**:

- Both secure connect bundle and input csv is loacted at `/path/to/` directory

**Table Structure**:

```
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> DESC TABLE projectjk;

CREATE TABLE projectjk.projectjk (
    fl_date date,
    op_carrier text,
    arr_delay float,
    dep_delay float,
    PRIMARY KEY ((fl_date), op_carrier)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (op_carrier ASC)
...;
```

**Starting with an empty table**:

```
token@cqlsh:projectjk> select * from projectjk;

 fl_date | op_carrier | arr_delay | dep_delay
---------+------------+-----------+-----------

(0 rows)
```

**Input sample csv file contents**:

```
% cat /path/to/projectjk.csv 
fl_date,op_carrier,dep_delay,arr_delay
2020-01-01,WN,44.0,363.0
2020-01-02,AN,42.0,143.42
```

**DSBulk configuration contents is**:

```
% cat projectjk.conf 
dsbulk {
 connector {
  name = "csv"
 }
 csv {
  url='/path/to/projectjk.csv'
  header=true
 }
 schema {
   keyspace=projectjk
   table=projectjk
 }
 log.stmt.level=EXTENDED
}
datastax-java-driver {
  basic {
    cloud.secure-connect-bundle="/path/to/secure-connect-projectjk.zip"
  }
  advanced.auth-provider {
    username = "CHANGE_ME"
    password = "CHANGE_ME"
  }
}
```

**DSBulk Load command executed is**:

```
./dsbulk load -f projectjk.conf
```